# How do I "mark" a file as safe against Windows Defender and/or Smart Screen?

Tags: file-management, anti-virus, windows-defender, microsoft-smartscreen

I have an .ahk script that I wrote myself that was quarantined on a separate work station.  I wasn't prompted (that I myself saw), and only realized it occured when I saw an error message on startup (AHK attempted to load the script but it wasn't there).  AFAIK, SmartScreen invokes a dialogue window when it prevents a file from opening, so I'm inclined to believe Defender was the culprit.  However, in either case, how can I "mark" or otherwise indicate to the system that a particular file is safe?  Or rather, regardless of whether it is safe or not, it is not to be disposed or otherwise hindered/tampered/intercepted/etc.?

Comment: If Windows Defender marked the file as a virus, then submitting the sample to Microsoft, will eventually result in the file no longer being marked as a virus.  In the case of Smart Screen, which is based on file reputation, that is based on several metrics no as easily changed.  Can you provide a screenshot of the what you see with the filename, that will determine, if it's Windows Defender or Smart Screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you suspect Windows Defender, you could store the AHK script in a folder
and then
[Add an exclusion to Windows Security](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/add-an-exclusion-to-windows-security-811816c0-4dfd-af4a-47e4-c301afe13b26)
for this folder (or for this file alone) :

> Go to **Start > Settings  > Update & Security  > Windows Security >
> Virus & threat protection.**
>
> Under **Virus & threat protection settings**, select **Manage
> settings**, and then under **Exclusions**, select **Add or remove
> exclusions**.
>
> Select **Add an exclusion**, and then select from files, folders, file
> types, or process. A folder exclusion will apply to all subfolders
> within the folder as well.